# C# code without the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Tags: c#, vb.net

If I include the visual.basic module in my C# project, I can do this:

`ParamVal = Strings.Space(1024);`

but how do I write that without `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;` - that is, without being able to access `Strings`?

(I can't run this through the online convertors...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
ParamVal = new String(' ', 1024);
```

The [String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) type has a constructor that allows you to specify a character, and how many times it should be repeated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll mark this as soon as my 12 minutes are up.

Comment: Stack Overflow at its best :)